# Trying to apply css to jQuery slideToggle when links are clicked

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, css, slidetoggle

Have a series of lists that I'm trying to show/hide using jQuery slideToggle, and need to apply a different css style to the hyperlinks that do the show/hide after they've been clicked, and then switch back to the original style once they're clicked again. Looked at this example as a resource: http://papermashup.com/jquery-show-hide-plugin/

In the snippets below, there is the following:

```
$(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
```

Tried using the following and it worked:

```
$(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText).css({ backgroundColor: '#399C05' }) : toggleClick.text(options.showText).css({ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' });
```

But I need to change the background image in the css instead of the background color like this:

```
$(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText).css({ background: url(/images/icon_image1.gif) }) : toggleClick.text(options.showText).css({ url(/images/icon_image1.gif) });
```

However, this shows “Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn’t support this property or method” and show/hide stops working.

Also tried switching the classes on click with:

```
$('#toggleDiv').toggleClass('show_hideClose', $(this).is(':visible'));
```

Where show_hideClose is essentially a duplicate of show_hide in the snippets below, and this resulted in the same error above.

So I have:

```
$('.show_hide').showHide({
    speed: 1000,  // speed you want the toggle to happen    
    easing: '',  // the animation effect you want. Remove this line if you dont want an effect and if you haven't included jQuery UI
    changeText: 1, // if you dont want the button text to change, set this to 0
    showText: 'View Available Programs', // the button text to show when a div is closed
    hideText: 'Hide Program Listing' // the button text to show when a div is open
});
```

and

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.showHide = function (options) {

        //default vars for the plugin
        var defaults = {
            speed: 1000,
        easing: '',
        changeText: 0,
        showText: 'Show',
        hideText: 'Hide'

        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $(this).click(function () { 

            $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing); 
            // this var stores which button you've clicked
            var toggleClick = $(this);
            // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
            var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
            // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
            $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
                // this only fires once the animation is completed
                if(options.changeText==1) {
                    $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
                    //$(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText).css({ backgroundColor: '#399C05' }) : toggleClick.text(options.showText).css({ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' });      //<-This works with background colors but not with background url
                }
            });

            return false;      
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The hyperlink is inside a .NET C# repeater and contains a repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMyContentGroups" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMyContentGroups_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>            
    <a href="#" id="blah" class="show_hide" rel='#                                                <%=rptmyContent.ClientID%>_programList_<%# GetDivClass() %>'>View</a>
        <div id="programList" runat="server" style="display: none;">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMyContent" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMyContent_OnItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>    
                <ul>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypContentDetail" runat="server" />
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>    
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

UPDATE:

Tried using:

```
$(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText).css('background-image', 'url("' + /images/icon_a.gif + '")') : toggleClick.text(options.showText).css('background-image', 'url("' + /images/icon_b.gif + '")');
```

IE says I'm missing a ) which I'm not. Visual Studio tells me: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".

Answer (score 0):

This is normally the proper syntax to change the background-image css property:

```
$(toggleDiv).is(":visible")
    ? toggleClick
        .text(options.hideText)
        .css('background-image', 'url(/images/icon_image1.gif)')
    : ...
```

But I strongly suggest you add an option to your plugin and use addClass/removeClass. This will make your plugin more customizable without hardcoding the url of the image in the code.

```
// pass the option
$('.show_hide').showHide({
    ...
    showText: 'View Available Programs',
    hideText: 'Hide Program Listing',
    hideClass: 'myClassForHide'
});

// use it in your toggle
$(toggleDiv).is(":visible")
    ? toggleClick
        .text(options.hideText)
        .addClass(options.hideClass)
    : toggleClick
        .text(options.hideText)
        .removeClass(options.hideClass)
```

Comment: Thanks, Didier. For some reason, I needed to use class="show_hide" to show and hide the extra content, otherwise the show/hide functionality broke. I did try using two different classes with the same properties and different images, but the problem with that was: when I tried setting unique id's to each hyperlink (they're in a repeater), show/hide broke. So... I found a solution that works for now, and will post that above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Looks like syntax and quotes made all the difference here. This seems to work:

```
$(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText).css('background-image', 'url(/images/image1.gif)') : toggleClick.text(options.showText).css('background-image', 'url(/images/image2.gif)');
```

Kicking myself for not trying that earlier.